# How do new function words develop in a language?

Tags: etymology, language-change, grammaticalisation

It's very understandable how new content words emerge in a language, since we can see it happening constantly in the modern day. On the other hand, I have trouble imagining the process by which a word like 被 (which is a particle marking a passive sentence in Chinese), can come to be added to a language.

Is there a good explanation of this process?

Comment: Do you know what [Grammaticalization](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammaticalization) is?

Comment: Specifically, the [grammaticalisation of 被 _bèi_ from](https://books.google.co.uk/books?hl=en&lr=&id=r9WO6g5mqi8C&oi=fnd&pg=PA28) [Old Chinese](http://homes.chass.utoronto.ca/~cla-acl/actes2004/Yin-CLA-2004.pdf) to [modern Standard Mandarin](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Hongming-Zhang-4/publication/301283160_The_Grammaticalization_of_'Bei'_in_Chinese/links/570ef68c08aee76b9dae0562/The-Grammaticalization-of-Bei-in-Chinese.pdf) is quite well-documented.

Comment: In Germanic languages the word for one became an article.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The process is known as "grammaticalization", and there is a ginormous literature on the topic. There are very many sources: here are a couple of examples. Many languages have a an expressive utterance like "pah!" or "bah!" signaling rejection – it's not even language. But it has become a post-verbal negative marker in a number of Lacustrine Bantu languages, for example Logoori *mba*. There is a verb *tak* "want" in many Bantu languages: it gets shortened to *ta* and is the future prefix on verbs in Swahili (also Shona). This is related to the use of "will" (want) as a future marker in English.